# Jenkins and Performance plugin report

Tags: performance, jenkins-plugins

I get the Performance Report Table but its not broken down by the URI. I have 2 APIs under test and expecting to see 2 line items but I see the only summary. clicking on summary also doesn't show the breakdown. Please see the screenshots below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing jenkins configuration.

The Source data files is supposed to be **/*.jtl (for octoperf load test) instead of **/*.log

[image]